# Azure Function - How to launch the excel document

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I created an excel report within the Azure function. I am trying to launch this excel file at the end of the process. But I get this error this is not supported in the OS.

I tried the following code.

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(reportSavePath);`

Comment: Why would you want Azure to launch Excel on their servers? What is that going to achieve? Do you instead want to launch Excel **on someone else's PC**?

Comment: Why? Do you understand that on "serverless server" excel wont be installed?)

Comment: @mjwills yeah I want to launch excel on the pc that is accessing my website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you open the newly created file will depend upon the type of trigger that you are using in your function. It doesn't make sense to try to open the file within the context of the function itself, as that is just code running on one of MS's server somewhere. You have a few options.

If you are using an HttpTrigger, you can return the file's byte stream in the response.

If you are using one of the queue, event, or timer type triggers, you'll need to save the file to some sort of external storage, like Azure Storage, before your function exits. You can then download the file from that storage.